# subset name of Any where Str|True: why does the name type match every type?

Tags: raku

I expected the refinement of the Any type to Str|True would make the `name` type match any Str or True, but this is what I see:

```
subset name of Any where Str|True;

sub go(name :$x) {
   say $x;
}

go(x => "hello");  #hello
go(x => True);     #True

go(x => 2);        #2
my @arr = 1, 2, 3; 
go(x => @arr);     #[1, 2, 3]
```

If I change the subset to `subset name of Any where Str|Bool`, then it works as I expect:

```
subset name of Any where Str|Bool;

sub go(name :$x) {
   say $x;
}

go(x => "hello");   
go(x => True);      
go(x => False);

go(x => 2);

--output:--
hello
True
False
Constraint type check failed in binding to parameter '$x'; expected name but got Int (2)
  in sub go at b.raku line 19
  in block <unit> at b.raku line 27
```

The `subset name of Any where Str|True;` was in the docs for [MAIN](https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli#sub_MAIN), which is the first place I encountered a subset.  So, the rule seems to be that you must declare types rather than instances of a type when refining a type with a subset.  But, then I tried:

```
subset name of Any where Str|2;

sub go(name :$x) {
   say $x;
}

go(x => "hello");
go(x => 2);
go(x => 6);

--output:--
hello
2
Constraint type check failed in binding to parameter '$x'; expected name but got Int (6)
  in sub go at b.raku line 19
  in block <unit> at b.raku line 25
```

Hmmm...the following seems to be the problem with True:

```
[197] > @arr ~~ True
Potential difficulties:
    Smartmatch against True always matches; if you mean to test the topic for truthiness, use :so or *.so or ?* instead
    ------> @arr ~~ ⏏True
True

[198] > 7 ~~ True
Potential difficulties:
    Smartmatch against True always matches; if you mean to test the topic for truthiness, use :so or *.so or ?* instead
    ------> 7 ~~ ⏏True
True

[199] > False ~~ True
Potential difficulties:
    Smartmatch against True always matches; if you mean to test the topic for truthiness, use :so or *.so or ?* instead
    ------> False ~~ ⏏True
True
```

Why would False match True?

Okay, according to the docs, the smartmatch operator aliases the lhs to $_, then calls `rhs.ACCEPTS($_)`, and for the Bool class ACCEPTS is defined to return the invocant.  Therefore, if True is on the rhs side of the smartmatch operator, ACCEPTS always returns True, and if False is on the rhs of the smartmatch operater, ACCEPTS always returns False, leading to this strange result:

```
[203] > False ~~ False
Potential difficulties:
    Smartmatch against False always fails; if you mean to test the topic for truthiness, use :!so or *.not or !* instead
    ------> False ~~ ⏏False
False
```

The result is that False smartmatches True, but False does not smartmatch False???

Comment: `False` is the opposite of `True`. Anything that tries to smartmatch `False` is `False`

Answer (score 5):

That's how e.g. you can write any normal test expression in a `given`/`when` and have it work; an expr that evaluates to a Bool will be used as the result of smartmatch, ignoring the "subject" of the match. Pretty expected behavior.

As for how to write the type you want, how about the plain vanilla:

`subset name of Any where { $_ ~~ Str || $_ ~~ Bool && ?$_ }`

Comment: Is the `?` mark needed?  Doesn't `&&` already put its operands in boolean context?

Comment: @7stud you're right, it's not needed. Leave it or remove it according to preference :)

Comment: Is this the same: `subset name of Any where ($_ ~~ Str) || ($_ eqv True);`?  According to the docs, `eqv` returns true only if both operands are of the same type and have the same structure.

Answer (score 3):

What @hobbs says is essentially true; however I'd maybe like to explain the sentence:

> an expr that evaluates to a Bool will be used as the result of smartmatch, ignoring the "subject" of the match. Pretty expected behavior.

That is, `Str | True` is a `Junction` equivalent to `any((Str), True)`. You can use a `Junction` for smartmatching, obviously, but its [behavior](https://rakudocs.github.io/language/operators#infix_%7C) will be:

> and then uses smartmatching to check whether [it] matches any of them

So what you have written above:

```
say Array ~~ Str | True; # Will return True
say <1 2 3> ~~ Str | True; # Yup, still True
say False ~~ Str | True; # Ditto
```

Any Junction like the one you have used to declare your `subset` with *always* return True, anything you match it with.

Comment: I'm not seeing that.  I get False for all your examples.  I now understand why a smartmatch against True will always return True, which I explained in my question.  However, the ACCEPTS method for the Str class does not work like the ACCEPTS method for the Bool class.  The smartmatch operator essentially calls `rhs.ACCEPTS(lhs)` and the ACCEPTS method for Str returns  `rhs eq lhs`.  So `Array ~~ Str` is equivalent to `Array eq Str` and `<1 2 3> ~~ Str` is equivalent to `<1 2 3> eq Str` and `False ~~ Str` is equivalent to `False eq Str`.

Comment: I'm using 2024.01, but It should work in the same way all over, I'd say. I'm writing it directly in the REPL. Anyway, the point is not what the ~~ returns for Str, but what it returns for Str | True... which is always True

Comment: `$ rakudo 
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2024.01.`  If we are seeing different results in rakudo, then discussing  anything is pointless.  Anyone else seeing `Array ~~ Str` is True?

Comment: "the `ACCEPTS` method for `Str` returns `rhs eq lhs`". If the `rhs` is *literally* `Str` then it should accept any *instance* of type `Str` (eg `'foo'`) or subtype thereof, OR any *type* object of type `Str` (eg `Str`, `Str:_`, `Str:D`, or `Str:U`) or subtype thereof. Only if `rhs` is an *instance* of `Str` (eg `'foo'`) should `ACCEPTS` do an `eq` comparison. So for me `say 'foo' ~~ Str` displays `True` whereas `say Str eq 'foo'` displays `False` and a warning. And `say Array ~~ Str`, by which I mean literally the 16 characters `s`, `a`, `y`, space, `A`, etc. in sequence, displays `False`.

Comment: @raiph, I'm just reading the docs.  Here is [ACCEPTS](https://docs.raku.org/type/Str#method_ACCEPTS) in the Str class, and the link in the description takes me to the `eq` operator.  The definition of ACCEPTS does specify the invocant has to be an instance of the Str class, so that means what I commented is wrong.  I don't know what happens when a type object is on the right of the smartmatch operator.

Comment: @jjmerelo, Sorry, I missed the `| True` in your examples.  For some reason, I thought that was part of the comment.  ***Any Junction like the one you have used to declare your subset with always return True, anything you match it with.***  Yes, and for non strings that's because of the way the smartmatch operator works for a Bool on the rhs, as I explained in my question, and which paradoxically returns False for `False ~~ False` and returns True for `False ~~ True`...which is NOT expected behavior for me!

Comment: @raiph, I think maybe the [ACCEPTS method in Mu](https://docs.raku.org/routine/ACCEPTS#(Mu)_method_ACCEPTS) is called when there is a type object on the rhs of the smartmatch operator. That performs a type check and returns True if the lhs is the same type as the type object on the rhs.  No details on how the type check is performed, e.g. when there is also a type object on the lhs of `~~`.